# Как правильно записать в tar архив данные в виде строк

Tags: c#, tar, archive

мне необходимо создать тар архив, в котором будут лежать csv файлы, из данных типа string(так же возможно использовать byte[]) на данный момент я пытаюсь сделать что то вроде этого

```
        public void ExportTAR(string tgzFilename, params string[] files)
    {
        using (var outStream = File.Create(tgzFilename))
        using (var gzoStream = new GZipOutputStream(outStream))
        using (var tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gzoStream))
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var file in files)
            {

                var tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateTarEntry("name"+i);
                // какие то действия чтобы записать в tarentry строки
                tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, true);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Этот код не работает? Как я понял, вы не tar архив, а tgz (.tar.gz) хотите создать?

Comment: грубо говоря, мне необходимо собрать архив из массива строк, каждая строка это отдельный файл(или по другому сказать - содержание этого файла, если будет понятнее)

Comment: Путь к файлу - так понятнее.